# Gradle - Exclude provided scope jars from War file

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

Gradle seems to claim that it doesnt include the providedCompile and providedRuntime scopes when building the war file.

But, when i do the build with below war config, a folder named "lib-provided" seems to be containing all the provided scoped jars. How do I limit this functionality to NOT include the provided scoped jars.

```
    configure(rootProject) {
    apply plugin: 'idea'
    apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
    apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
    apply plugin: 'java'

    targetCompatibility = 1.8
    sourceCompatibility = 1.8

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
        maven { url "https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/" }
    }

    // Import Spring Boot's bom, spring-boot-dependencies
    dependencyManagement {
        imports {
            mavenBom 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:1.2.5.RELEASE'
        }
    }


    // Override the spring-data-releasetrain.version property
    ext['spring-data-releasetrain.version'] = 'Fowler-SR1'

    dependencies {
        compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
        compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")
............ Other Spring Boot based projects
        testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")

        compile("com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-hibernate4:2.4.6")

......... Below are the "Provided" Scoped packages

        providedRuntime("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat")
        providedCompile("org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper:8.0.23")
        providedCompile("org.hibernate:hibernate-core:4.3.7.Final")
        providedCompile("org.hibernate:hibernate-infinispan:4.3.7.Final")
        providedCompile("org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:4.3.7.Final")
        providedCompile("org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:5.1.3.Final")
        providedCompile("org.hibernate:hibernate-search-orm:5.0.1.Final")
        providedCompile("org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:4.0.4.Final")
        providedCompile("org.infinispan:infinispan-core:7.1.1.Final")
        providedCompile("org.infinispan:infinispan-query:7.1.1.Final")

        testCompile("com.microsoft.sqlserver:sqljdbc41:4.1")
    }


    configurations {
        providedCompile

        // replaced with jcl-over-slf4j
        all*.exclude group: 'commons-logging', module: 'commons-logging'
        // replaced with log4j-over-slf4j
        all*.exclude group: 'log4j', module: 'log4j'
    }

}
war {
    baseName = 'abc'
    version =  '5.0.0-SNAPSHOT-' + + System.currentTimeMillis();
    doFirst {
        manifest {
            attributes("Implementation-Title": project.name, "Implementation-Version": version, "Implementation-Timestamp": new Date())
        }
    }
    webAppDirName = 'web'
    includeEmptyDirs false
    archiveName 'abc.war'
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Where to folder `lib-provided` is located in the project structure? What the purpose of this folder?

Comment: I do not have any lib-provided folder in my structure.. I think it is being created by Gradle based on the packages specified under "providedCompile"

Comment: Don't think so. Could please provide an example of invalid build?

Comment: I added the code which does the java compile.. Please see my edit.

Comment: It seems that there's no need to add `providedCompile` configuration. It should be added from scratch.

Comment: I had to add providedCompile due to some error during the build (Gradle didnt understand providedCompile). Now, it works fine without that keyword too. But, still.. it doesnt solve my actual issue of having the provided libraries in lib-provided folder within the .war file.

Comment: Without a runnable example it will be difficult to help.

Comment: After some more googling, I found that Spring Boot plugin does that (Referring to http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html)

Comment: Great, glad You've worked it out! :)

Answer (score 0):

In the below configuration,  Gradle 4.6 
None of the below depndnecies will be in the War/WEB-INF lib.

If you have an Ear build.gradle can contain entry like below , which will ensure all depndence jar in the Ear/lib folder.

if the below entry is made, The generated Ear file will have .war file and the War/lib folder will not be having the specified dependent files.

```
apply plugin: 'war'
earlib project(path: ':MyWebProject', configuration: 'compile')
deploy project(path: ':MyWebProject', configuration: 'archives')


apply plugin: 'war'
dependencies {

providedCompile('org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-web') 
providedCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web') {
     exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-tomcat" 
}
```

}